# How to use ByteStream to read 1Mb of a file into a string

Tags: java, guava, readfile

What I have now is using FileInputStream

```
int length = 1024*1024;
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(new File("foo"));
fs.skip(offset);
byte[] buf = new byte[length];
int bufferSize = fs.read(buf, 0, length);
String s = new String(buf, 0, bufferSize);
```

I'm wondering how can I realize the same result by using ByteStreams in guava library.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops sorry. I meant length there. I just modified my code

Comment: Honestly, the way you have it now is probably shorter than what you would have with Guava. The `ByteStreams` api really only has methods to read all bytes, not bytes starting from some offset. You can read all the bytes and only use `offset` to `length`, but then you haven't really gained anything from switching to Guava.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with Guava:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.asByteSource(new File("foo"))
    .slice(offset, length)
    .read();
String s = new String(bytes, Charsets.US_ASCII);
```

There are a couple of problems with your code (though it may work fine for files, it won't necessarily for any type of stream):

```
fs.skip(offset);
```

This doesn't necessarily skip all `offset` bytes. You have to either check the number of bytes it skipped in the return value until you've skipped the full amount or use something that does that for you, such as `ByteStreams.skipFully`.

```
int bufferSize = fs.read(buf, 0, length);
```

Again, this won't necessarily read all `length` bytes, and the number of bytes it does read can be an arbitrary amount--you can't rely on it in general.

```
String s = new String(buf, 0, bufferSize);
```

This implicitly uses the system default `Charset`, which usually isn't a good idea--and when you do want it, it's best to make it explicit with `Charset.defaultCharset()`.

Also note that in general, a certain number of bytes may not translate to a legal sequence of characters depending on the `Charset` being used (i.e. if it's ASCII you're fine, if it's Unicode, not so much).

Answer (score 2):

Why try to use Guava when it's not necessary ?

In this case, it looks like you're looking exactly for a RandomAccessFile.

```
File file = new File("foo");
long offset = ... ;
try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")) {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1014*1024];
  raf.seek(offset);
  raf.readFully(buffer);
  return new String(buffer, Charset.defaultCharset());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a more elegant solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final int offset = 20;
    StringBuilder to = new StringBuilder();

    CharStreams.copy(CharStreams.newReaderSupplier(new InputSupplier<InputStream>() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getInput() throws IOException {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(new File("pom.xml"));

            ByteStreams.skipFully(fs, offset);

            return fs;
        }
    }, Charset.defaultCharset()), to);

    System.out.println(to);
}
```

The only advantage is that you can save some GC time when your `String` is really big by avoiding conversion into `String`.